# BFGMiner + CGMiner solo mining, how to specify payout address

Tags: cgminer, mining-reward, miner-configuration, bfgminer

I am currently trying my luck at solo mining a few types of crypto-currencies. My question is why does BFGMiner require a `--coinbase-addr-` argument for solo mining to know where to payout rewards to and CGMiner does not?

I am because today I found a block with BFGMiner in Terracoin mining and it seemed to not have payed me even though I specified a coinbase address. I want to make sure that if I am so lucky to find a block again that I actually get paid.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=309486.new#new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the parent's support of the coinbasetxn capability. When your (getwork or getblocktemplate) request includes the coinbasetxn flag, the response may (should) contain an address for the payout to go to. Some blockchain implementations support this flag and some don't. A number of miners allow you to specify the address manually. Some don't. Most pool software uses the username instead of the coinbasetxn return as the coinbase address.

You can see this changeset here were local mining support was added to lbrycrd. (Disclaimer: I work for them). https://github.com/lbryio/lbrycrd/commit/24269e177f002eb6975abe077bd727992381a95d

Comment: Edge of my seat for 6 years.. Thanks for the answer!